# Android Volley Post JSON Array with paramater and getting response in JSON Object

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am facing strange problem with Google Volley I hope some one help me out quickly. I want to send JSON array in parameter and server will give me response in JSON object. How can we achieve this?
e.g
I wanted to post this JSON array.

```
    [
     {
    "name":"John",
    "age":"30",
    "cars":"6"
    },
    {
    "name":"John",
    "age":"30",
    "car
     }
    ]
```

and server will send response in JSON object format like this.

```
{
"status":"success",
"code":30,

}
```

Can someone explain to me how I can achieve this thing?. Moreover, my JSONarray consist of mobile contacts and size will be large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<Object, Object>` where value be collection of json Element you want. You can make custom deserilizator with lib like "gson".

You should try: `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSON_STRING);`

Comment: i am not sure ether you understand problem or not.

Comment: @MalikQasimAliGouri you wanted like this: [{name:item}{name:item}...{name:item}]. you get like this: {name:item}{name:item}?  it's problem?

Comment: yes i want to send json array and server will give response in json object.

Comment: all json object is pair key-value. you get here pair like {empty object:Json Objects} you need take from root pair {value1:value2} and create "new JSONArray(value2)"